# Raditator fluid leaking

Tags: chevrolet, overheating, equinox

I have a 2005 Chevy Equinox and it was over heating. So we replaced the water pump. Then we replaced the A/c compressor, it had a crack in it. So we thought everything was all good. No when we went to add more fluid, it started it leak. It looks to be coming from somewhere underneath the alternator, it looks like it maybe coming from the block. Please help??

Answer (score 2):

You need to confirm where the leak is coming from. Make sure it's not coming from the water pump gasket. If it is there are products available to help with water pump gasket sealing.

Make sure the intake gasket isn't leaking.

IIRC on some 3.4l engines, there are plastic coolant elbows that crack or go soft and break. They go from the alternator bracket to the engine block. You can determine if your car has them by the style of bracket on the engine. If it's a large bracket that has heater pipes coming out of it, than that's likely your leak. There are two of them. Most parts stores carry replacements that are made of aluminum or plastic and come with new o-rings.

If you have the thinner style bracket there is a metal tube that runs by the alternator for the heater hoses.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need to do first : look under you vehicles for the wet spots :then Get some radiator coolant dye so when your Vehicle built-up pressure in the radiator The radiator coolant dye will come out where The leak is ..